# Make Symfony clear cache from times to times

Tags: php, caching, symfony, cpanel

i'm with an cool problem with symfony.
Our client system is growing... fast... very fast...
Suddenly i got an error, system goes down, and when i opened the CPANEL, i see this message.

```
Disk Quote Exceeded
```

Look at error:

[image: Disk Quote Exceeded]

BUT! we have all stats of server on 15% or low...

```
1.5GB from 15GB of disk space.
5gb montly transf. from 100gb
etc...etc..
```

I found this is because i have reached 100.000 files on FTP.
barely all is from Symfony Cache.

How can i make symfony clear cache from times to times? To use most recently itens only... Not all itens as cached itens?

I found some help on documentation, but only usefull if i did created mannualy the cached itens.

Those 100.000 files was auto generated cache, from default configuration.

I dont know why this is happening, because i have another similar system, with 5x more users than this one and does not have reached this number yet...

Hope someone give an clue to solve this issue! Ty!

Answer (score 1):

the  easiest  solution  it's  to clear  it in  cron

```
5 */3 * * 1-5  /bin/php /path_to_app/app/console  cache:clear -e prod
```

But remember. cache is creating for a reason...

Comment: Symfony create cache to make system fast